# How to debug cordova with good efficiency

Tags: cordova

I run a build command every time I debug cordova on my device.

```
cordova emulate ios(or android) 
cordova run ios(or android) --device
```

But, it is inefficient to execute the command every time with a few static file modifications.

Is there any better way?

My app uses Google Maps Plugin as a native plugin.

Comment: I use Visual Studio to build, deploy, emulate, etc. without the command line. You could try NetBeans if you are not running Windows, it also features some (limited) Cordova support.